# Comma seperates objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have inputs where user can enter numbers and whenever user puts comma between numbers I want to make new Object.

For example, user insert "23, 24, 25" and presses enter, I want to get 3 objects(23, 24, 25) and push them in array.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: 24 is not an object. It is an integer. Please show effort and expected output. `arr = input.value.split(", ");` would perhaps be what you are looking for?

Comment: See [AngularJS ng-list Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you could use a html form to trigger a function like this:

```js
var myArray = [];

function createObject(id) {
  return {
    id: id
  }
}

function pushToObjArray() {
  document.getElementById("objectIds").value
    .split(",").forEach(function(id) {
      var myObj = createObject(id);
      myArray.push(myObj);
    });
  console.log(myArray);
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript: pushToObjArray()">
  <input type="text" id="objectIds" />
  <input type="submit" value="GO!">
</form>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qydkpmrw/

Comment: thats what i need

Answer (score 1):

Reference Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

str.split(separator) will return array for you.

```js
let input = "23,24,25";
let data = input.split(",");
console.log(data);
```